# Python thread name keeps on increasing (self.name - 1,2,3 ...)

Tags: python, multithreading

I using a thread in Python in a loop. Every 5 minutes it will create threads and complete.
I am logging thread name, and it seems to increasing.

Suppose its runs for two hours, the thread name goes to  200, does it cause any problem like not clearing thread memory? Or is it not a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [specify thread names](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) yourself if you want to. If you do not supply a name, Python will insert `Thread-N` for you, where `N` is an increasing integer.

From the referenced docs:

> class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
>
> ...
>
> name is the thread name. By default, a unique name is constructed of
>   the form “Thread-N” where N is a small decimal number.

You probably don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks csl..I was worried abt name..now relived

Answer (score 0):

Each new thread gets a new, unique identity (name). Identities of long gone threads won't be reused.

Also you can't start infinite amounts of concurrently runnning threads. This example will fail eventually:

```
import time
import threading,thread

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            #print "I am %s" % self.getName()
            time.sleep(0.01)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 1
    while True:
        print "Starting thread #%d..." % count
        MyThread().start()
        count += 1
```

If you add some error handling, you will see, that you can start a new thread once one of the "old" ones finished.

```
import time
import threading,thread

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            #print "I am %s" % self.getName()
            time.sleep(0.01)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 1
    while True:
        try:
            print "Starting thread #%d..." % count
            MyThread().start()
            count += 1
        except thread.error:
            time.sleep(0.05)
```